# How to replace this value with a true NA value

Tags: r

I currently have this code:

```
HLNfixed <- HLN %>%
  mutate(
    Values = case_when(
      Values < 0        ~ "NA",
      TRUE ~ as.character(Values) 
    )
  )
```

Where if a value of 'Values' is less than 0 i want it to be replaced with the greyed out NA in a dataframe, but I cannot work out how to do this other than giving it the string of NA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're already using `dplyr` you can use `na_if()`

```
library(dplyr)
  HLNfixed <- HLN %>%
  mutate(
    Values = case_when(
      Values < 0        ~ "NA",
      TRUE ~ as.character(Values) 
    )
  )  %>%
  na_if("NA") %>% 
  mutate(Values = as.numeric(Values))
```

Comment: @Slopegraphhelp, if this answer solved your problem please accept it by clicking the checkmark

Comment: Ahh very sorry - a quick follow up: is there any way of doing this so that the column is still considered numeric as I need to use this data for a function which requires this.

Comment: @Slopegraphhelp assuming that the non `NA` values in `Values` are originally numeric add a `mutate` call `mutate(Values = as.numeric(Values))`

Comment: Where in the code would this be added sorry I can't get it to work i am a complete novice

Comment: @Slopegraphhelp - just at the end.  See edited answer